# Short story about aliens sending messages to Earth and prime math being key to decoding

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I read this short story probably in the 2000s, but I don’t know how old it was then.

Story beats I remember:

- Aliens decided it was too much work to actually travel, so they just beamed messages to other planets.
- We receive a message and are struggling to decode it.
- There is the usual math stuff that is universal and easy to figure out. Like symbols for adding and equals and digits and primeness.
- Then the message introduced a statement like “1 @ prime” — and this turned out to mean “maybe” because a civilization could reasonably define 1 as prime or not.
- From this small beginning of a subjective word, the message was able to finally escape the dry world of math.
- The message was a DNA sequence and instructions to make an alien clone. This was how the aliens “traveled” to other planets.
- The humans that decoded the message built an alien and raised it and story ended happily.

I’ve always loved that maybe-prime jump from math to more interesting topics. But I have never been able to remember the name of the story.

Comment: You've put ***"1 @ prime"*** into quote marks. Is this intended to be a direct quote that you recall from the book?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you read this in a magazine or an anthology (or online)?

Comment: Primes being used in decoding is common in sci-fi... and in reality.  See for example the [Arecibo Message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message).

Comment: Valorum, no sorry that was not meant to be a direct quote, just an example — there was some sort of alien symbol for “maybe” between the symbols for “1” and “prime”. Good question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It isn't a short story, but the idea that 1 perhaps is prime is part of decoding the alien message in Robert J. Sawyer's novel [*Rollback*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?210881) (2007).

> "You're right. It *is* a debatable point. One is definitely an odd-ball as primes go. And two — well, it’s not an *odd*-ball; it's an *even*-ball.  That is, it's the only even prime number. You could just as  arbitrarily define the set of primes as all *odd* numbers that have precisely two whole-number factors. If you did it that way, then two isn't a prime."
>
> "Ah."
>
> "See? That's what they're conveying. Delta is a symbol that means, I think, 'It's a matter of opinion.' Neither answer is *wrong*; it's just a matter of personal preference, see?"

The novel also matches the part about the aliens sending the information required to clone bodies for certain individuals to meet other intelligent races:

> "It's a — a blueprint, I guess you could call it."
>
> "You mean for a spaceship? Like in *Contact*?"
>
> "No. Not for a spaceship." She looked briefly at Gunter, then back at Don. "For a Dracon."
>
> "*What?*"
>
> "The bulk of the message is the Dracon genome, and related biochemical information."
>
> He frowned. "Well, um, I guess that'll be fascinating to study."
>
> "We're not supposed to study it," Sarah said. "Or at least, that's *not all* we're supposed to do."
>
> "What then?"
>
> "We're supposed to" — she paused, presumably seeking a word — "to *actualize* it."
>
> "Sorry?"
>
> "The message," she said, "also includes instructions for making an artificial womb and an incubator."
>
> Don felt his eyebrows going up. "You mean they want us to *grow* one of them?"
>
> "That's right."

The book ends with Don and his new wife Lenore raising two Dracon children alongside their own children.

It's not a short story, though, it's a complete novel.  It was, however, serialized in *Analog* in 2006, so that might be confusing you.

Comment: [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)

Comment: That must be it! Memory is fickle and it must have been a full novel. Thank you so much!